# How to make CSS file more important than another CSS file?

Tags: html, css

I want all the Classes,Tags and Ids within `css.css` overwritten over `bootstrap.min.css` **without repeating** the Classes,tags and Ids of `bootstrap.min.css`.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: What do you mean? css.css will overrule bootstrap.min.css, but only for those rules that are defined in css.css.

Comment: Answering this is can be lengthy, as this is a vague subject. There is a whole chapter about this on the w3 website. [CSS Cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade)

Comment: @GolezTrol exactly. without using`!important` or repeating everything.

Comment: @alnassre Did you mean to open up this can of worms or were you just looking for a simple answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no such magic. CSS has its own principles, such as the cascade, and you cannot switch them off.

You can place the reference to `css.css` after the reference to `bootstrap.min.css`, but this is just one factor in the process of resolving how CSS rules will be applied. Adding `!important`, which is generally a symptom of wrong design, is just yet another factor: an `!important` rule in an earlier file may override your `!important` rule, if its selector has higher specificity.

To override CSS rules, you need to analyze the rule you wish to override and set up a rule that “wins”, by the cascade principles.

Comment: umm, It look like that no magic solution  yet.

Comment: @alnassre Like I said, you won't be able to find a good answer about this, almost all the answers here are correct but all of them are lacking. I strongly recommend for you to read this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html try it out, and then after having an idea on how it works, you will be able to ask more specific answers about the subject.

Comment: The "higher specificity" was the right tip. I have `div.x` and on some divs additionally to `x` a `selected`. That didn't work until i switched in the CSS from `div.selected` to `div.x.selected`. Now, `selected` has higher priority.

Answer (score 13):

Simple, include the more important CSS file last.

Comment: This isn't enough. If you have `div .some-class{}` in the less important css file, you cannot overwrite it with `.some-class{}` but it MIGHT be overwritten with `p .some-class{}` depending on the HTML structure. It is far more complicated then just having the order of the CSS files. Especially since the OP says `without repeating the Classes,tags and Ids`, it isn't quite clear what he wants, but I think it means he doesn't want to use the same rules.

Comment: @Dan, this question is simple enough to warrant a simple answer. You are, of course, correct in what you say, but the title of the question relates purely to making one file more important than another.

Comment: @Dan, although I'm on your side on this, I'd rather close-vote the question that to give an answer that eventually doesn't answer the underlying question and therefor won't add much value.

Comment: If you inject a page, with jquery load for instance, you have not such a control. So it is not so easy sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

I can only give you an example.

Lets say Bootstrap.css has the following
`.rules #world {border:0px;}` [specificity 110]

and css.css has the following
`div #world{border:20px;}` [specificity 101]

In this case, bootstrap.css will always override css.css. So, I advise you to add a container to all of your content - give this container a id..lets say "god" and then add the prefix .god to all of your styles in css - but again, this is not as simple, and depends a lot on how you get your calculations right.

```
#god div #world{border:20px;}
```

This is a length topic as someone else pointed out - so you'll have to basically know what all bootstrap is doing to your page and what is css.css doing.

You can always look up this wonderful article which never gets old http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Adding to this: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 2):

When you include a stylesheet, it overwrites all declarations of the *before* included stylesheets. If you change your includes to:

```
<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Bootstrap is later included and will overwrite propertys from css.css.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This isn't enough. If you have `div .some-class{}` in the less important css file, you cannot overwrite it with `.some-class{}` but it MIGHT be overwritten with `p .some-class{}` depending on the HTML structure. It is far more complicated then just having the order of the CSS files. Especially since the OP says `without repeating the Classes,tags and Ids`, it isn't quite clear what he wants, but I think it means he doesn't want to use the same rules.

Comment: Yes. But with the code he provided this is the only solution I can directly offer.

Comment: @TobiasSpringer that's totally the opposite. the `css.css` is in there right order, what @Dan said is my exactly needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could do one thing is that include only css.css and @import "css/bootstrap.min.css" within css.css so your code will be like this

**Within html**

```
<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and **Within css.css**

```
@import "css/bootstrap.min.css"

.bootstrap_class{//your style..}
.hero-unit{background: red;}
```

Using this trick you can override bootstrap styling without any Showing results for headache  this

Answer (score 0):

if you cant alter the files, and the order of the call of the css file is not working, you can always use !important, 
but that is gonna comsume a lot of time becuz you need to add it on every line of css.

ex: display: inline !important;

Answer (score 0):

Refer it last item in a list which will always override previous style sheets

Below will force your page to fit 980px since it overrides the previous stylesheet property

Example

**Style1.css**

```
 #main{ width:1000px;}
```

**Style2.css**

```
 #main{ width:980px;} 
      or  
 #main{ width:980px !important;} /* if needed only */
```

**HTML**

```
<link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="main"></div>
```