# Use different Css files in different part of sing html file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem with css files, to be more detailed i have linked 2 css stiles in one html file one is style.scc and bootstrap.css I am using bootstrap social button and that's why i need bootstrap. but this movement has changed almost everything in my site...
 so is there a way to call bootstrap.css file in single div and in aver divs to have original css file?

PS css Scoped property don't works from me!

Comment: Why not copying the styles from the bootstrap file into your style.css?

Comment: becous i don't want to mes with enormous lines of code of bootsrap

Comment: Then there's the option to make a custom file: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible, if you only using bootstrap for social button - just copy styles from bootstrap.css to your stylesheet (style.css).

Scoped CSS works only in Firefox for now.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap already has a feature in their site to help you doing custom builds, check it using the following link: [`Customize`](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/).

Also, you can always get the source code and working with it by yourself.

For more information, check the following link: [`Compiling CSS and JavaScript`](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt).

Answer (score 0):

Never mynde i founde the solution from "[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029470/how-to-make-css-file-more-important-than-another-css-file)"

you mast set the mos important css file the last and the least important first
  :-)